# In the Chrome browser(version 109) , Drag and Drop not working due to Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name') at cacheFile

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, web-applications

In my web application, We have drag and drop feature in the table ui. it(drag and drop feature) is not working in the latest chrome browser - 109. However it is working in 108 and below chrome versions. We are getting error in the browser console.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')
> at cacheFile (content.js:28:22)
> at HTMLDocument. (content.js:148:13)

browser content.js method:

```
function cacheFile(file) {
    var fName = file.name;
    var fSize = file.size;
    var fModification = file.lastModified;

    pageFiles.add(file)

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ 'inputfile': { name: fName, size: fSize, modification: fModification } });

 
}
```

we don't have content.js in the our application. the file exists in the below path of the chrome browser:

chrome-extension://fhkbechcecepmohakoafeoobnliolhei/content.js

Comment: Have you tried Chrome Canary?  It generally has the next available build that could help you get an insight in case the issue would only happen under 109. Depending on that we could report it directly.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I will check

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I have installed chrome canary & tried but no luck. Still getting same error in the console

Comment: Hi, anyone please help on this issue

Comment: We have found the issue. We are using Even.Path variable propery  in the code of Drag and Drop  Event.Path property is not supporting in the chrome v.109. but we have handled alternative way. Drag & Drop is working fine now. but still , same error showing in the console window.